# SQL Server - add calculated column who fills data based on a gap between months by user id

Tags: sql-server, time, conditional-statements

sql server 2014:
I am looking to add a calculated column based on the gap between row's month and previous month, matched by the a user's ID only (kinda like a pivot table). It needs to be dynamic.

**calculated column needed:**
 $174.00 (Agent=1004, month=3) - $164.00 (agent=1004, month=2)

I've added a screenshot explaining a lot:

[image: PIVOT table]

Thank you!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: previews or previous?

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: Post sample data as text instead of image

Comment: Is number of records per month is fixed. Currently it four.. Is it always four ?

Comment: @Prdp, let's not apply that restriction on solutions we'd be presenting, almost all scenarios will not be restricted as such, and it's almost certainly of easy/medium difficulty to handle.

Comment: no, it depends on the data

Comment: @AviadAmar - can you copy that excel data and post it here

Comment: @AviadAmar - Is it possible to get month 1 to have 4 records and month 2 to have 5 records and in that case what is the expected result

Comment: yes. it should be like this: $174.00 (where Agent=1004 and month=3) - $164.00 ( where agent=1004 and month=2)

Answer (score 0):

This, you should have provided (*sadly, I can only assume your schema*):

```
CREATE TABLE #TESTJACK(Id int, SomeMonth int, Balance int)
INSERT INTO #TESTJACK VALUES (1001, 1, 385)
INSERT INTO #TESTJACK VALUES (1002, 1, 986)
INSERT INTO #TESTJACK VALUES (1001, 2, 157)
INSERT INTO #TESTJACK VALUES (1001, 3, 587)
INSERT INTO #TESTJACK VALUES (1002, 3, 321)
DROP TABLE #TESTJACK
```

This, seems to replicate your Excel file's behavior in SQL, for the schema provided:

```
SELECT TJ2.Id, TJ2.SomeMonth, TJ1.SomeMonth, TJ2.Balance, TJ1.Balance, TJ2.Balance - TJ1.Balance AS Diff
FROM #TESTJACK AS TJ2
LEFT JOIN #TESTJACK AS TJ1 ON TJ1.Id = TJ2.Id AND TJ1.SomeMonth = TJ2.SomeMonth - 1
ORDER BY TJ2.SomeMonth, TJ2.Id
```

Clean `NULL`s using `ISNULL`, put some aliases same like `Diff`, figure what columns you wanna keep or kill, that's your game now.